Flutter hot restart speed on Windows
PC1 - CPU i5 8500, RAM 16GB, GPU 2GB
PC2 - CPU i9 10850K, RAM 64 GB, GPU 16GB
Above specs just FYI. Systems are almost the same, both running Windows 11, have installed VS Code with flutter/dart plugin.
I have issue like on PC1 medium size project, doing hot restart takes under 5 seconds, while on PC2, even the start template after just changing simple thing takes up to 1-2 minute. I do not remember if I changed anything but what could be a problem ?
I am running projects on both system with
flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname 0.0.0.0 --web-port 5000

Did you try Flutter pub clean and after flutter pub get in this new one? You also can try flutter pub cache clean. If you are trying it on a browser, also try to select it after click in Hot Reload. Restart everything also works sometimes.

Hey. Sorry for late answer. I have tried it but I think there is something like version related to vscode or plugins in vscode. I tried now in vmware virtual machine. Created some Ubuntu machine, downloaded flutter and added to path, installed vscode via snap (--classic), added flutter and dart extensions on vscode and it is working like a charm. I do not know for why it should be problem outside of vm. For me for now  it is not comfortable to work from vm and that's why I asked. Thank you for your time and attention.
